# 1つのWEBアプリが複数ベンダーのDBを参照することの是非

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql, database, hibernate

サーバー上にデプロイされたWEBアプリケーション（仮にSpringBootベース）が
データソースとして Postgres DB と MySQL DB と言った
異なるベンダーが提供する2種類のデータベースを参照するアーキテクチャは
一般的に問題ない構成なのでしょうか。

同一ベンダーであれば、複数DBを参照するケースは
検索する中で多々見かけましたが、
異種ベンダーとなるとあまり見かけることがありません。

ORMにHibernateを使用する場合、
それぞれのSessionFactoryを作成すれば実現可能であるため
こういった構成も問題ないように思えます。

浅学のため大変恐縮ではございますが、
参考までに、掲題の構成を採用しているシステムや、
是非について書かれている記事,書籍等あれば教えていただけないでしょうか。

Comment: 商用にするにはライセンス料金が余計にかかるだけなのでやらないんぢゃないかな・・・

Comment: 是か非かと聞かれたら、一つで済ませることができるという選択肢があるなら「非」という答えになると思いますけど。

Comment: @774RR
コメントありがとうございます。
確かに、コスト面で見ると片一方のDBで期待する機能を実現できるのであれば、こういった構成を取るのは無駄と言えますね。

Comment: @WebSurfer 
コメントありがとうございます。
DBの役割を片一方のDBのみで担えるのであれば「非」であると言うことについては、私も同意見です。

Postgres/MySQLとは別に、
DynamoDBやCloud SpannerなどのNoSQL/NewSQLと言ったような
前者にはない特性を持ったDBも使用したい場合は、こういった構成も取りえるのかと考えます。

Comment: 「DynamoDBやCloud Spanner」とかは自分は触ったこともないのでその利点は分かりませんが、経験のある SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite などで何の問題もないなら、そのうちどれかにするというのは普通だと思うのですが。

Comment: 普通に複数のシステムでDBを参照してると、あるんじゃないかと思う構成かと思います。本体は複数のOracleだけど、他の小さなシステムがSQL ServerとかMySQL/PostgreSQL辺りを使ってて、そういうシステムの隙間を埋めるシステムで複数種類を参照する事例はあると思います。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

永続オブジェクトをリレーショナルデータベース(RDB)に、セッション情報やキャッシュなど消えても良いデータはオンメモリなキーバリューデータベース(キーバリューストア、KVS)にというのはよくある構成かと思います。扱うデータの特性に応じて、**特性が異なるデータベース(DB)を組み合わせる**というのはそれほど不思議とは思いません。

たぶん、聞きたいのは、ほぼ同じような特性のDBを複数種類使う是非なのかと思います。例えば、MariaDBとMySQLはほぼほぼ同じRDBですが、データをそれぞれのDBに分けて扱う理由があるのかどうかです。

そもそも、DBを分けると言うことがあるのかです。最初に述べたとおり、必要な特性が異なるデータであれば、特性毎に扱うDBを分ける意味もありますが、ほぼ同じ特性のデータを別々のDBを分ける意味があるのでしょうか？ないですよね？全く関連が無いデータ同士は違うDBに入れるべきとか、聞いたことが無いです。そもそも、全く関連がないデータ同士を扱うなんて、一つのアプリケーションとして、何か間違っているような気もします。

それでも、いくつかのフレームワークでは複数のDBをサポートしています。これは一体、どういう用途に使うのでしょうか？たぶんですが「既存の別のシステムのDBに接続するため」だと私は思っています。例えば、すでに運用中のシステムAがあるとして、それと連携するシステムBを作るとしましょう。理想としては、システムAが連携用のAPIを提供して、それを利用すべきかもしれませんが、工数等の問題から、システムAのDBを直接参照することになったとします。ただ、システムA自体は変更したくないので、システムBが独自に持つデータは別のDBで扱うとなります。こうなると、システムBでは、システムAのDBとシステムB独自のデータがあるDBの二つを参照することになります。システムAのDBは既に運用中なので変更できません。ライセンスとか、費用とか、サーバーの制限とか、パフォーマンスとか、サポートの有無とか、上司の趣味とか、プログラマーのこだわりとかで、システムBのDBは、別ベンダーのDBになるというシチュエーションはあり得るかと思います。

何を言いたいかというと、そもそも、DBを分ける時点で、なにか退っ引きならない理由があり、それによっては、ベンダーが異なることも避けることはできないのでは無いのかと言うことです。問題があるかどうか言う前に「**やるしかない**」という状態です。もちろん、検証段階でうまくいかないことが発覚することもあるでしょう。そうであれば、計画の段階からやり直し(それこそ既存のシステムから作り直しなど)はあるかも知れません。逆に、同じベンダーが提供するDB同士、例えば、Orcale Database、MySQL、Berkeley DBはいずれもオラクル社が提供していますが、それらを組み合わせて作ったシステムでも問題がでてくるかも知れません。もし、そういうことが心配というのであれば、より具体的な構成を挙げた上で問題点があるか検証する必要があるかと思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
ご説明された内容で
運用中の別システムのDBに接続するため。というシチュエーションであれば、
複数DBを参照するのは取りうる構成だと思えました。